# differential equation/Lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I want to show that the $ (t_- , t_+) $ of $$ y'=\cos y \sqrt{t^2+y^2},  y(0)=\pi$$ 
is $ (t_- , t_+) =\mathbb R$
Therefore I want to show, that f is Lipschitz.

$$ \bigg|\cos y_1 \sqrt{t^2+y_1^2} - \cos y_2 \sqrt{t^2+y_2^2}\bigg|\leq \bigg|\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}+\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2} \leq\bigg| \frac{t^2+y_1^2-t^2-y_2^2}{\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}-\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}}\bigg| $$
This leads to nothing, because I have "-" at the denominator. 
Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$
 f: \Bbb R \times (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R \, \\
 f(t, y) = \cos y \sqrt{t^2+y^2}
$$
is locally Lipschitz continuous with respect to $y$ because the partial derivative
$$
   \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(t, y) = -\sin y \sqrt{t^2+y^2} + \cos y \frac{y}{\sqrt{t^2+y^2}}
$$
exists and is continuous in $ \Bbb R \times (0, \infty)$. Therefore the initial value problem
$$
 y' = f(t, y) \, , \quad y(0) = \pi
$$
has a unique solution in a neighbourhood of $t=0$, and that solution has a “maximal interval of existence” $(t_- , t_+)$. If $t_+ < \infty$ then
$$ \tag{*}
 \lim_{t \nearrow t_+} |y(t)| = \infty
$$
must hold, and similarly for the left boundary. (The solution “blows up” at the boundaries of the existence interval. See for example “1.5 Intervals of Existence” in  [Christopher P. Grant: Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations](https://math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/theoryofodes2008.pdf).)

Now the initial value problems
$$
 y' = f(t, y) \, , \quad y(0) = \pi/2 \\
 y' = f(t, y) \, , \quad y(0) = 3 \pi/2
$$
have the *constant* solutions $y_1(t) = \pi/2$ and $y_2(t) = 3\pi/2$, respectively. Because of the local uniqueness of solutions, $y, y_1, y_2$ cannot intersect, so that
$$
   \pi/2 < y(t) < 3 \pi/2
$$
for $t \in (t_- , t_+)$. In other words, $y$ is *bounded* and $(*)$ cannot hold.

Consequently, the maximal existence interval of $y$ is $(t_- , t_+) = (-\infty, \infty) = \Bbb R$.

*Remark:* $f(y, t)$ is not globally Lipschitz continuous with respect to $y$ since the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(t, y)$ is not globally bounded. Therefore  Lipschitz continuity alone is not sufficient to show that the solution exists on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have only one question to this:Now the initial value problems
$$
 y' = f(t, y) \, , \quad y(0) = \pi/2 \\
 y' = f(t, y) \, , \quad y(0) = 3 \pi/2
$$

Comment: This initial value problems discribe theEquilibrium points? I don't get, why y(t) is bounded, because they don't intersect?

Comment: @Leon1998: $y(t) \ne \pi/2, 3\pi/2$ because they cannot intersect. And since $\pi/2 < y(t) < 3 \pi/2$ holds for $t=0$ the same relation must hold everywhere (think of the intermediate value theorem for continuous function).

Comment: Ah ok I see. It is $y_1=\pi/2$  for all t. Then I get it

Comment: Then I also see, that the  maximal existence interval is R, because y is bounded and cannot blow up

Comment: Thank you very much:). It helped a lot:)

Comment: @Leon1998: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$\cos(y_1)\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}-\cos(y_2)\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}+\cos(y_2)\sqrt{t^2+y_2^2}-\cos(y_2)\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}$$
The first summand is $$\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}(\cos(y_1)-\cos(y_2))=\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}(y_1-y_2)(-\sin(\xi))$$ by the mean value theorem.
And $$\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}-\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}=(t^2+y_2^2-t^2-y_1^2)\cdot \frac {1}{2}(t^2+\eta^2)^{-1/2}2\eta$$

Comment: I didn't get that right, Then you would estimate the first two terms and the two last terms? Then I would have "-" in the denominator again?

Comment: Also by the mean value theorem.

Comment: Then I would get: $ |\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2}(y_2-y_1) + \frac{(y_1^2-y_2^2)  \cdot \xi}{\sqrt{t^2+\xi^2}} |\leq | |\sqrt{t^2+y_1^2} (y_2-y_1) + (y_2-y_1)(y_2+y_1)| $

Comment: What can I do now?